# Outlook built-in Junk email options

Tags: microsoft-outlook, spam-prevention

I am running Outlook 2007 on Windows Vista. The first time when Outlook detects junk mail it displays a dialog which states:

> "Outlook has downloaded a message that appears to be Junk E-mail. This message was automatically moved to the Junk E-mail folder..."

and offers several options. It also displays a check box labeled:

> "Please do not show this dialog again."

I have checked that check box and the dialog box is no longer displayed.

I'm bad about not paying attention to the junk folder and on occasion legit emails are sitting in there. I looked all in Outlook Options and couldn't find anywhere to turn that back on. Is there a way to turn that notification back on?

Answer (score 2):

Following steps should help you:

- start Registry editor (select *run* from start menu, enter *regedit* and press ok) and go to the following key: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Outlook\Options\General`
- find the `PONT_STRING` key - it should contain several numbers separated by comma (they represent each dialog that has the *never show again* option checked)
- remove number `37` from this list

source and more information: http://www.slipstick.com/OUTLOOK/showdialog.htm